# declaring 3d array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to declare (not define) three dimensional array in PHP and then assign values to it.

For example,

```
<?php
$item = array(
   array("item1", 22, 18),
   array("Item2", 15, 13),
   array("Item3", 5, 2),
);
?>
```

This is how I want my array. I first want to declare this `$item` array and then assign those three values (e.g `item1, 22, 18`) to it. Please help me with this and also how to access this array.

Comment: start from the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: `$item = array(); $item[] = array("item1",22,18); $item[] = array("Item2",15,13); $item[] = array("Item3",5,2);`

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted a three-dimensional array.  The current array you have is two-dimensional.

What you might have meant was to have "item#" as a key to your array.

```
<?php
$item = array(
  "item1" => array( 22, 18 ),
  "Item2" => array( 15, 13 ),
  "Item3" => array( 5, 2 ),
);
?>
```

You would access an element with `$item['item1']`, which would give you the array `(22,18)`

Comment: Not really I want Item as my key, rather I need item to store value just  as other two values.. and moreover I have confusion on how to declare it first and then assign values..